# Hard drive being recognised as SD/MMC?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a 500GB Seagate GoFlex. On my laptop it comes up as "Local Disc" but on my brother's computer - the one I am using now - it comes up as "SD/MMC".

Here is an image of the problem (the drive on the far right):

[image]

How can I get it to be recognised as a hard drive?

Comment: Can you go the *Run* prompt (press Windows key and R) enter *diskmgmt.msc* and post a screenshot please?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: all I did was change its assignment from drive G: to E: and it was fine afterwards.

Comment: Some card readers or card reader drivers come with software that adds icons to the drive letters.  Possibly you ran into a conflict or glitch with such software.